# PHP TWIG Как поместить в option value больше чем одно свойство?

Tags: php, html, twig

```
<select id="itemSelect">
  {% for item in items %}
      <option value="{{ item.value }}">{{ item.text }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Мне нужно иметь доступ не только к value но и к другим свойствам item в JS, как мне поместить в option value больше чем одно свойство?

Comment: Можно положить свойства в джсон и загнать в data-атрибут. Можно отдельно от селекта сгенерировать js-массив и по ключу `option[value]` вытаскивать нужные данные. Можно просто накидать свойств через разделитель.

Comment: @u_mulder, можно пример?

Comment: Пример чего именно?

Comment: @u_mulder, JSON и data-атрибута